# Use existing persistent profile with selenium, firefox and python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, profile

I want to automate some OSINT tasks on web.whatsapp.com, but I don't want to login each time selenium initiates the session. It proved surprisingly difficult to get a reliable solution with persistent cookies, but see my solution below.

Many existing solutions suggest generating a FirefoxProfile(), e.g.

```
fp = FirefoxProfile()
```

Various ways are suggested to include a "path" into `fp`. `fp` is then included in an `Options()` object and handed to `webdriver.Firefox()` upon launch.

I tried many variants of this, but I think the approach is fundamentally flawed because `fp` represents an actual profile itself which you can then hand over to the driver... That's NOT what you need when you want to use an already existing profile which holds the cookies to keep you logged in.

Answer (score 3):

There is a firefox-specific way to pass an existing profile to the webdriver using set_capability [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions). Here's how I used it:

```
profilepath = '/your/profile/path'
options = Options()
options.set_capability("moz:firefoxOptions", {
    "args":["-profile", profilepath]
})
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

This worked for me and proved a much simpler approach to some of the hacks I've seen being used.